# does anybody know this window manager

Tags: window-manager, twm

I am connecting to a cluster with the window manager as in the picture. Does anybody know which WM it is? It does not have even a menu I can open like in twm[image]

Comment: twm has a menu if you configure one.

Comment: cool, how do I do that?

Comment: It could be a lot of different window managers; try `ps axl` from that terminal.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch and what should at look in the output?

Comment: On your initial login, how many processes do you have?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I run ps xl -u <username> and I get 9 processes, of which one is called twm

Comment: but in twm if u click with the mouse you can open a menu, here I don't even manage to resize xterm

Comment: @simona Then you're using `twm` - the tabbed window manager; You might prefer one of the `twmrc` files [here](http://xwinman.org/vtwm.php).

Comment: this was due to a mistake in the configuration file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like good old twm, which a lot of X systems will use as their Window manager when installed in "minimal" mode.  It is possible to make windows to launch applications and what not in these old school Window managers, but, in the classic UNIX tradition, it requires editing text files to pull off.

The file to edit is `~/.twmrc` or, equivalently, `$HOME/.twmrc`, and, as Elliott pointed out, there are a few example template twmrc files available online.

Further reading:

- [Twmrc configuration files](http://xwinman.org/vtwm.php)
- [Twmrc manual](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/twm.1.html)